# View records on a view page by clicking the links

Tags: eloquent, laravel-5.1, show, laravel-blade

How do I view each individual record? Each record is a link, if clicked, it should display the record on the view page.

```
 Route::get('question/{$id}', array('as'=>'question', 'uses'=>'QuestionController@show'));
```

THis is hte show method to display:

```
public function show($id = null)
    {
        return view('questions.view')
       ->with('title', 'Make it Snappy - Question')
        ->with('question', Question::find($id))
        ->with('users', Auth::user()->username);
    }
```

This is the index.blade.php page

```
 @extends('layouts.default')

@section('content')
    <h1>Ask a Question</h1>

    @if(Auth::check())
        @if($errors->has())
            <p>The following errors have occured:</p>
            <ul id="form-errors">
                {!! $errors->first('ask
                ', '<li>:message</li>') !!}
            </ul>
        @endif

            {!! Form::open(array('url' => 'ask', 'method' => 'post')) !!}
            {!! Form::token() !!}

            <p>
                {!! Form::label('question', 'Question') !!}<br />
                {!! Form::text('question', Input::old('question')) !!} <br />

                {!! Form::submit('Ask a Question') !!}
            </p>
            {!! Form::close() !!}
            @else
            <p>Please login to ask a question.</p>
    @endif
    <div id="questions">

        <h2>Unsolved Questions</h2>


        @if(!count($questions) > 0)
            <p>No questions have been asked</p>

        @else
            <ul>
                @foreach($questions as $question)
                    <li>{!! Html::linkRoute('question', str_limit($question->questions, 35), $question->id) !!} by 

                        @if(count($users) > 0)
                            @foreach($users as $user)
                                @if($user->id === $question->userid)
                                    {!! ucfirst($user->username) !!}
                                @endif
                            @endforeach
                        @endif
                    </li>
                @endforeach
            </ul>

            {!! $questions->render() !!}    

        @endif
    </div>
@stop
```

[image: Error message returned]

[image: The index.blade.php page]

All i want is that when I click on any of the questions it should be displayed on the view page. I appreciate your support.

Comment: I think you havent specified route ? are you using resource controller

Comment: Sorry for the late reply. The route is what I specified at the top of the code. The first line. Am I doing it wrongly?

Comment: can you show me your url ?

Comment: {!! Form::open(array('url' => 'question', 'method' => 'post')) !!}

Comment: That's the URL. Thanks. i appreciate your concern and support.

Comment: Route::get('question/{$id}', array('as'=>'question', 'uses'=>'QuestionController@show')); This is the route.

Answer (score 0):

```
 Route::get('question/{$id}', array('as'=>'question', 'uses'=>'QuestionController@show'));
```

your route accepts get while ur form method was post so it couldnt find get request so try making it get

```
{!! Form::open(array('url' => 'question', 'method' => 'post')) !!}
```

try it

```
{!! Form::open(array('url' => 'question', 'method' => 'get')) !!}
```

Comment: Thanks. The form do 2 things.  Accepts the input for questions and display the questions. I'll edit the post and post the full code for index.blade.php. So the one you referred to is for posting which is working fine. The link is to display the question on the view page. I believe the implementation I'm following has changed because it's Laravel 4 which is very different in implementation to the latest Laravel 5.1.* framework I'm working with.

Comment: I have edited and posted the complete code for index.blade.php

Comment: yes you are right but one form can handle both post and get if you want to make it happen just pass flash session to check if its get check it to the method and make it get if post make it to post hope you understand

Comment: It sounds like greek to me because I'm a newbie in Laravel. I'll really appreciate if you can help with the code snippet of the implementation.

Comment: you want to handle both post and get from the single form ?

Comment: If that would solve the problem, it'll be a nice thing to do.

Comment: make 2 different page one handles post insert and next view page  its the best practice